# Accessing long Tcl list

Tags: list, tcl

I have a following long tcl list:

```
>> puts $res
{ banner { } }  { report { { name {{ columns { {head1} {head2} {head3} {head4} {pin} } } { { row_1 { { } {-0.008} { } {r1} {hier1} } } { row_2 { {1000} {-0.009} {-0.000} {r2} {hier2} } } } } } } }
```

I need to access the value 1000 in row_2.

Though I am able to get the value using the following, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this rather than specifying lindex so many times.

```
 >> set val [lindex [lindex [lindex [lindex [lindex [lindex [lindex [lindex $res 1] 1] 0] 1] 1] 1] 1] 0]
 >> 1000
```

Comment: Technically, this is a _deep_ list and not a _long_ list…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lindex` command can take multiple indexes, so you can do:

```
set val [lindex $res 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0]
```

Comment: You can also pass the indices as a list: `lindex $res {1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0}`. The difference isn't significant when you're working with literals, but when working with computed or user-supplied indices it's very nice.